# Rendering link within a Modal from reactstrap library

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm rendering a Modal from reactstrap library, and i want to have within this text modal another link tag. Something like "Click here to show it". So, when the modal appears, the user can see that text and also can click on the here word to render another different Modal. How can achieve that? 
This is my code:

code where i'm calling the Modal

```
<Modal
  show={showGeneralModal}
  children={"Click " + <a href="#"> here </a> + " to show it"}
  title={modalTitle}
  size={modalSize}
  onExit={this.toggleNormalModal}
/>
```

code from the original exported Modal

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={isOpen}
          backdrop="static"
          keyboard={false}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          size={size}
          onExit={onExit}
        >
          <ModalHeader className={modalHeaderClasses} toggle={this.toggle}>
            {title}
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody className={modalBodyClasses}>
            {children}
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
```

I'm getting right now this text within the modal:

`Click [object Object] to show it`

And i would like to have instead

`Click here to show it`

and when i click on `here` word, the other Modal should be rendered.

Any suggestions?

I can't modify the original Modal code cause it is being used for many other components in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, i was in a wrong way to do that. If you are in the same trouble, you may know that `children` is an already prop of react which allows you to access whatever you passed in the component that you are accessing to.

Knowing that, you don't have to pass `children` prop, just pass within the component whatever you want to be inside of children prop. So, instead of doing this:

```
<Modal
  show={showGeneralModal}
  children={"Click " + <a href="#"> here </a> + " to show it"}
  title={modalTitle}
  size={modalSize}
  onExit={this.toggleNormalModal}
/>
```

do this:

```
<Modal
  show={showGeneralModal}
  title={modalTitle}
  size={modalSize}
  onExit={this.toggleNormalModal}
> Click <a href="#"> here </a> to show it
</Modal>
```